# How many coupon codes I can create at a time in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, coupon-codes

I want to create 1 Million coupon codes.
What is the maximum no. of coupon codes I can generate at a time?
I tried to generate 0.2 Million coupons at a time but it displays error like

> maximum execution time reached

And I set unlimited execution time but no use.

Kindly help me.

Comment: After creating this amount of coupons did you notice a performance problem in your cart?

Comment: @lloiacono i imported 6m coupons and my checkout page is now deadly slow.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you reached the maximum execution time in PHP. You can update this by updating your PHP ini file setting. This can be done a number of ways depending on your PHP install. By default PHP sets this to 30 seconds. Magento provides a sample php.ini file which resets this to 300 *minutes*.

Update your php.ini file with the following:

`max_execution_time = 18000`

Or set it to 0 to be unlimited.

Source:

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Edit:

---

After you make these changes you should restart Apache/nginx and/or PHP-FPM. The changes to ini files will not take effect until after a restart of the services.